# Recording the areas the participant clicks in user testing

Tags: usability-testing, prototype

When user testing a prototype, how would you note the areas the participant clicks when interacting with the prototype and present these to stakeholders?

I have not got a heat map of the interactions as the test was done in person. I watch the recoding and note where the participant clicks but when I share these results with stakeholders I am wondering what is the best way to share this info to show where the participant is focussing their attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best option would be to present the data visually, this will be more effective when sharing with stakeholders.

[image]
source: https://www.usertesting.com/blog/click-maps